# What is this circuit board for? (HAF cooler master case)

Tags: desktop-computer

[image: circuit board]

Second hand case with no manual. There are no cables coming out of it at all, just an 4 pin power connector, and two esata ports (I think).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your post and attach the picture.

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: Sorry about that, jumped the gun with regards uploading an image!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like the connection for a hot-swap drive bay. Is the front of that enclosure a space for harddrives to be inserted and removed?

You have there a 4-pin power connector and two SATA ports. There should be two drive bays on the front that you can remove and put drives into, and if you connect those ports on the back to your motherboard and power supply, you'll be able to use the drives.

Comment: +1 - I think we all hit the correct points of the image.

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be the back side of a SATA dock. These are usually in place so that a sliding bracket with a HDD/SSD can be attached from the front instead of opening up the case.

Basically, you have two SATA ports there and a 4 pin Molex to power the drives. The SATA ports that are visible in that pick would be connected to your mobo along with power to the Molex from your PSU.

Pop the drive into the adaptor, then slide the adaptor into the front slot and your drive is connected.

Answer (score 2):

That green box is part of their "X Dock" hot swap drive bays.

It is for easy swapping out of two drives from the front of the case without opening the inside of the box. See this question from their FAQ "[How do I use the Hotswap bays?](http://www.coolermaster-usa.com/faq.php?action=ViewAnswer&faq_id=240)"

Comment: @Darth Android - you guys typed faster than me...;)